# Закрыл ли пользователь окно PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Работаю с PyQT5.
Подскажите, как выполнить определенное действие после закрытия окна?
И где мне писать это условие, что если закрыл, то печатай одну фразу?
Например вывести фразу "программа закрыта":

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(458, 170)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 171, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 90, 71, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 458, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "Какое вывести сообщение:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести"))


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go)

    def go(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(text)

    # когда пользователь закроет программу, должно вывестись сообщение: Программа закрыта.
    # но как узнать когда он закрыл окно и закрыл ли он его вообще?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в классе переопределить метод `closeEvent`, [например](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7782103a5d91125d2df23a869b448747a383111d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__ask_before_close.py#L22):

```
class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go)

    def go(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(text)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(
            self, 'Вопрос', 'Точно хотите закрыть?',
            QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No
        )
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```